# How to select item with the biggest price?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

as you can see I am working in SQL Developer and trying to get some data out of my tables.

I'm trying to get out the item with its biggest price, but don't know how to manage it.
For price I was trying

SELECT MAX(price)
FROM price

but I get return 95€, when the biggest price is 350€.

Can someone help me, that I Will get the biggest price (from table Price) and the name of item (from table Item) ?

EDIT: Here are my tables, if that helps you

```
INSERT INTO ITEM VALUES (1, 'Item one', 1);
INSERT INTO ITEM VALUES (2, 'Item two', 1);
INSERT INTO ITEM VALUES (3, 'Item three', 2);
INSERT INTO ITEM VALUES (4, 'Item four', 2);
INSERT INTO ITEM VALUES (5, 'Item five', 3);
INSERT INTO ITEM VALUES (6, 'Item six', 3);

/* CREATE TABLE ITEM(
ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
NAME VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
TK_ORG INTEGER NOT NULL
); */

INSERT INTO PRICE VALUES (1, 'normal', '50 €', 1);
INSERT INTO PRICE VALUES (2, 'special offer', '45 €', 1);
INSERT INTO PRICE VALUES (3, 'normal', '80 €', 2);
INSERT INTO PRICE VALUES (4, 'special offer', '150 €', 2);
INSERT INTO PRICE VALUES (5, 'normal', '40 €', 3);
INSERT INTO PRICE VALUES (6, 'special offer', '25 €', 3);
INSERT INTO PRICE VALUES (7, 'normal', '70 €', 4);
INSERT INTO PRICE VALUES (8, 'special offer', '45 €', 4);
INSERT INTO PRICE VALUES (9, 'normal', '95 €', 5);
INSERT INTO PRICE VALUES (10, 'special offer', '320 €', 5);

/* CREATE TABLE PRICE(
ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
PRICE_TYPE VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
PRICE VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
TK_ITEM INTEGER NOT NULL
); */
```

Comment: Is it mysql or oracle database? What is the data type of price? Post the create and insert table statements.

Comment: the price's datatype is – ?

Comment: Provide some sample data and expected result.

Comment: if its including the euro sign, then its not an integer, so by string sorting 95 would be higher than 350 (9 > 5)

Comment: Also MAX() uses a lot of memory and if the table grows the query can take quite a lot of time to load. I find that if whatever language you are using alongside if at all, that you will be looping through the data; it's better to find the largest number that way with some form of flag that changes if the current number is larger. But again i'd only do that if I was looping through my results for another reason anyway. Although if you were to only select the price then you could loop through them in whichever language to work out which is larger. This could be better performance too.

Comment: Just don't use more queries than you need :)

Comment: I also think you should use an integer data type and add the euro sign in your code that you are pulling the data too. As this is better practice and will allow you to use different currencies if you wished.

Comment: By definition, a price is an amount, i.e. a number. Don't store it in a text field. Use a numeric type for the column. The best type for amounts of money in MySQL is [`DECIMAL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fixed-point-types.html) because it stores the exact value (as opposed to float/double that store an approximated value).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, change the column type to integer. Right now, I assume, it is VARCHAR or TEXT. As it sorts by the first symbol, of course 9 > 3, that's why you get the weird results. Remove the € from the row's content and move it to another column.

Comment: Is possible to get name of item, which cost the most, even if these informations are not in same table?

Comment: provide some more information on the database structure

Comment: Check original post, I think there is enough Infos for it, or?

Comment: `SELECT price.price, item.name FROM price LEFT JOIN item ON item.id = price.tk_item ORDER BY price.price DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: What is that part doing?  `LEFT JOIN item ON item.id = price.tk_item ORDER BY price.price DESC LIMIT 1' `

Comment: it joins the other table by the similar keys so that you can get the item name

Comment: SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"

Comment: Right! When I deleted tgat oart DESC LIMIT 1 it started working, but I got all of the prices, not just the biggest one.

Comment: try this - `SELECT TOP 1 price.price, item.name FROM price LEFT JOIN item ON item.id = price.tk_item ORDER BY price.price DESC`

Comment: SQL Error: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"

Comment: `SELECT * FROM ( SELECT price.price, item.name FROM price LEFT JOIN item ON item.id = price.tk_item ORDER BY price.price DESC ) WHERE rownum <=1`

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Sorry for the few wrong queries, it's been a while since I last worked with Oracle/MSSQL and I'm confusing them :)

Answer (score 4):

You would seem to be storing the price as a string and not as a number.  In MySQL, you can use silent conversion to get what you want:

```
SELECT MAX(price + 0)
FROM price;
```

In Oracle, for this example, you can just do:

```
SELECT MAX(to_number(replace(price, '€', '')))
FROM price;
```

although a regular expression would be more flexible if you had more currencies.

Comment: Thank you, for that! What is the best way to get name of item too, not just the highest price?

Comment: Is that even possible, because lines I want are not in same table?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove € from your price and convert it to integer.
Adding € means your price is not a number . Fist we convert it to number these we get max result

```
 SELECT MAX(CONVERT(REPLACE(pricing,' €',''),UNSIGNED INTEGER)) FROM price
```

Comment: [Code-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148274/246338)

Comment: Is possible to get name of item, which cost the most, even if these informations are not in same table?